# Featured image editing

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

Hello,
Is it allowed to change the image I submitted to the featured image contest? I don't mean change it to a completely different image, only minor contrast/saturation tweaks...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think its a bad idea.  I can think of one particular image lately that got changed (crop and contrast change) and I liked it **MUCH** better before - and not everybody checks back often here and might not realize they voted for a picture they no longer like.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it and it could lead to some "cheating"... I asked because it's not clear from the rules, but thinking about it I agree with you that it's not a good idea.